# pdf viewer with two-sided option

Tags: gnome, pdf

I am looking for a pdf viewer, that is able to show two pages side-by-side, like they would be printed in a book. (Just like Preview does on Mac OS X)
I am using GNOME on Debian and already looked into evince and xpdf.

Just to be clear: I do only want to show the pages this way, printing is of no concern.

Thanks in advance. :)

Update:
Thanks to John WH Smith I found the option "Dual" in the settings, which does exactly what I want. I have been very blind though o.O

Comment: What's wrong with using `evince` with the *Dual* and *Odd pages left first* options activated (View menu) ?

Comment: Okular is also pretty good. Terrible things have been done to the Evince user interface. I now think Okular is better.

Comment: @Marcel If your question has been answered, you can close it.